# Laravel 5.2 - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::session()

Tags: session, laravel-5

I am using session in Laravel 5.2 and here is my Controller code :

```
if ($request->session()->has('username')) {
        return view('dashboard');
}
```

I need to use session, and getting this error :

> FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 21: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::session()

How to resolve it ?

Comment: make sure to add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Answer (score 25):

Not sure where you have `$request` coming from, but more than likely you have the wrong type being injected.

If you just want the `$request` instance you would want to use `Illuminate\Http\Request`

Kinda looks like you are having the Facade injected instead.

`Request` (in root namespace) is the Facade that is aliased.

`Illuminate\Http\Request` is the actual request class you want the instance of.

Comment: Well it's on controller. I have already defined use Illuminate\Http\Request at top. But the session has() method is not working.

Comment: that error means it is the wrong class being injected. so unless that error in your post is resolved, you aren't even making it to the `has` call.

Answer (score 21):

Try put this at your file begin:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

I had the same problem and solved this way.

Answer (score 0):

Hey If you are using laravel 5.2, this is worked for me.

Put your controllers in 'web' middleware. like,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
  //routes here
});
```

and Make sure kernel file has middleware classes registered.

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \Perkweb\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \Perkweb\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

Comment: I did the same. But well I think I figure out the problem. My problem was, I couldn't use  `$request->session->has('key')`. The problem was I just created session like `session('key')` . But if I used `$request->session()->put('key', 'value');` then it might work!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Session facade like that.

On the top..

```
use Session;
```

In your controller method..

```
if (Session::has('username')) {
    return view('dashboard');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your variable **$request** to another variable name. for example **$requestApp**.

Here is the code :

```
if ($requestApp->session()->has('username')) {
    return view('dashboard');
}
```

because $request by default is belong to use Illuminate\Http\Request;